# Estoy obteniendo: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chart-api

Tengo una pequeña funcion que se encarga de obtener una serie de datos:

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.importarEstadisticas = function()
{
  $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'mainApp/Estadisticas/estadisticaMeses.php'
    })
    .then(function successCallback(datosEstadisicasMeses)
    {
      $scope.tableEstadisticas = datosEstadisicasMeses.data;
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart()
      {
        var cabeceras = Object.keys($scope.tableEstadisticas[0]); //Aqui se obtiene los valores Fecha y Registros, para las cabeceras de tu grafico.
        var formatoGrafico = [];
        formatoGrafico.push(cabeceras); //Se dejan como primer elemento en el arreglo Formato.
        $scope.tableEstadisticas.forEach(function(registro, index) {
            //Se recorren los datos y se cargan al arreglo con el mismo formato.
            formatoGrafico.push([registro.Fecha, registro.Registros]);
        });

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([formatoGrafico]);

        var options =
        {
          title: 'Gráfica de Visitantes',
          hAxis: {title: 'Fecha', titleTextStyle: {color: 'Black'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    },function errorCallback(datosEstadisicasMeses)
    {
      console.log("Error, al tratar de traer los datos")
    });
}
$scope.importarEstadisticas();
```

Datos que retorna la consulta(En producción):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos que retorna el Array(Local):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero obtengo un resultado en la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo o que se está omitiendo para que genere dicho error mencionado con anterioridad?

Comment: Y cual es el tipo de datos que le especificaste en las `cols`?  Date?

Comment: No, no lo he especificado, tal vez sea eso?

Comment: Intente espeficicarlo y me dices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que especificarle el formato de fecha que el valor sera parseado:

```
var options =
        {
          title: 'Gráfica de Visitantes',
          hAxis: {title: 'Fecha', titleTextStyle: {color: 'Black'}, format: "yyyy-MM-dd"},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };
```

Y tambien deberias de eliminar el primer resultado del array ya que te esta retornando los nombres de las columnas y ese es un valor que no puede ser convertido a fecha:

```
//...

.then(function successCallback(datosEstadisicasMeses) {

    // verificamos que tenga datos
    if(datosEstadisicasMeses.length>0)
    {
            // eliminamos el primer registro
            datosEstadisicasMeses.splice(0,1);
    }

    //...
```

Comment: Todos los objetos que retornan estan en tipo String, las cabeceras se le añaden a la posicion 0 para que pueda determinar que parte pertenece cada dato. He probado mucho pero pues aun asi no encuentro solucion.

Comment: A pesar de que no he podido solucionar el problema, se que te tomaste el tiempo y te doy la recompensa, mejor eso a que se pierda. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta aquí:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([formatoGrafico]);
```

Debe ser así:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(formatoGrafico);
```